# Python: Convert json with extra data error into CSV

Tags: python, json, parsing, export-to-csv

I have a JSON in below format which I receive from a different team and not allowed to make any changes to it:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "5603bbaae412390b73f0c7f",
            "name": "ABC",
            "description": "Test",
            "rsid": "pwcs",
            "type": "project",
            "owner": {
                "id": 529932
            },
            "created": "2015-09-24T09:00:26Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "56094673e4b0a7e17e310b83",
            "name": "secores",
            "description": "Panel",
            "rsid": "pwce",
            "type": "project",
            "owner": {
                "id": 520902
            },
            "created": "2015-09-28T13:53:55Z"
        }
    ],
    "totalPages": 9,
    "totalElements": 8592,
    "number": 0,
    "numberOfElements": 1000,
    "firstPage": true,
    "lastPage": false,
    "sort": null,
    "size": 1000
}
```

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "5bf2cc64d977553780706050",
            "name": "Services Report",
            "description": "",
            "rsid": "pcie",
            "type": "project",
            "owner": {
                "id": 518013
            },
            "created": "2018-11-19T14:44:52Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "5bf2d56e40b39312e3e167d0",
            "name": "Standard form",
            "description": "",
            "rsid": "wcu",
            "type": "project",
            "owner": {
                "id": 521114
            },
            "created": "2018-11-19T15:23:26Z"
        }
    ],
    "totalPages": 9,
    "totalElements": 8592,
    "number": 1,
    "numberOfElements": 1000,
    "firstPage": false,
    "lastPage": false,
    "sort": null,
    "size": 1000
}
```

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "5d95e7d6187c6d6376fd1bad",
            "name": "New Project",
            "description": "",
            "rsid": "pcinforrod",
            "type": "project",
            "owner": {
                "id": 200904228
            },
            "created": "2019-10-03T12:21:42Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "5d95fc6e56d2e82519629b96",
            "name": "Demo - 10/03",
            "description": "",
            "rsid": "sitedev",
            "type": "project",
            "owner": {
                "id": 20001494
            },
            "created": "2019-10-03T13:49:34Z"
        }
    ],
    "totalPages": 9,
    "totalElements": 8592,
    "number": 2,
    "numberOfElements": 1000,
    "firstPage": false,
    "lastPage": false,
    "sort": null,
    "size": 1000
}
```

I am trying to convert it into CSV using below code:

```
import csv
import json
with open("C:\python\SampleJSON.json",'rb') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

fname = "workspaceExcelDemo.csv"

with open(fname,"w", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow(["id","name","rsid"])
    for item in data["content"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item['id'],item['name'],item['rsid']])
```

However I am getting below error message while executing the above piece of code:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 35 column 1 (char 937)
```

How do I convert the above JSON into CSV without making any changes to the JSON file?

Comment: In the post before last edit there was "=======" in the last string of file. This causes an error.

Comment: @Hihikomori yes after each block of "content" node there is ======= which is causing the error but is there any way to skip ======= and convert the all the information present under each content node to csv?

Comment: So you need to read the file as a string then make `blocks = files_text.split("=======")` and then get jsons `jsons=[json.loads(block) for block in blocks]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and the comments well you could use the [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) method:

```py
import csv
import json

with open("C:\python\SampleJSON.json",'rb') as file:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in file]

"""

The json.dumps method converts a Python object to a JSON formatted string.

The json.loads method parses a JSON string into a native Python object.

Replacing the "=" character with an empty string.

"""
data = json.loads(json.dumps(data).replace("=", ""))

fname = "workspaceExcelDemo.csv"

with open(fname, "w", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow(["id", "name", "rsid"])
    for item in data[0]["content"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item['id'], item['name'], item['rsid']])
```

Comment: I still have the same error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\***Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.load(file)
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 35 column 1 (char 937)

Comment: I made an edit involving the object received by json in a list because `json.loads`(and `json.load`) doesn't decode many json objects and therefore it interprets the rest of the file as additional data